# Mystery circuit breaker discovered in QO panel

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I have part ownership of a house and acreage these days in rural southern Missouri.  The house was built before the AHJ (county) adopted the NEC, so there are some quirks in the electrical system, one of them being the electrical panel (located in the master bath).  Thankfully, the panel itself is a Square D QOC-16D Series L1 (and not some terrible piece of fire-protection-eliminating trash), but of course, it's underdocumented and stuffed to the gills with double-stuff breakers, including the two in the photo below in slots 11 and 15 in the panel that are of a style I have never seen before:

[image: closeup of slots 11/13/15 of the panel]

Did Square-D ever make a double-stuff QO with the handles in the configuration depicted, and if so, when? If not, who the heck made them?  Are these oddly configured breakers obsolete in some way, compared to their more conventional double-stuff brethren (as exemplified by the QO2020 in slot 13 seen between them)?

Comment: Those look like 3rd party breakers.   Have you pulled one out for writing or label looking?

Comment: Although power was said to be shut off to the house, we did not have tools with us to remove the panel deadfront, so no.

Comment: Actually... http://forums.mikeholt.com/showthread.php?t=121156 they may be a squareD OEM breaker.. I can find several in Google images mostly on EBay

Comment: I have a half bad one in my hand now, it's squareD.

Comment: Tyson it is easy to change over to the side by side but the inline ones can be found on e bay or other online sites.

Answer (score 3):

I have both styles of these breakers. If you look on the left side you will see the square D logo embossed in the case.
The ones I have came out of an older panel. They work fine but I needed to upgrade from the 15,20 to 20,20 like you have. So the answer is yes square D made these or this style.

Answer (score 3):

IIR, these were the original Square D tandem style breakers.  They changed from a "piggy-back" style to "side-by-side" in the mid 1980s.  We have a ton of Square D around this area and I run into these all the time in older houses.