# How are "R handles" different from the rest in a Square D QO panel?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I have an older Square D QO 200 amp load center which looks to be from the early 1980s based off the green sticker.

I noticed closer to the bottom of the panel that the breaker spots are listed as “R handles” and found a sticker on the inside of the panel that details it but I am still a little confused as to what the difference is between R handles and the regular spots higher up.

From my interpretation, are the R handles intended for single pole tandem breakers? Is it acceptable to have single pole breakers/circuits on these handles along with the 20 amp 240v double pole breaker for the mini split?

This is mostly for curiosity sakes but also plan to add two circuits for a kitchen remodel and want to make sure I plan accordingly.

Thanks thanks for the time and I apologize for any formatting issues with my post and pictures.

[image: Panel]

[image: Label]

Comment: A picture of the panels showing all the breakers would help a lot.

Comment: I edited to get the pictures working properly. Could still use one showing the *actual breakers as installed*.

Comment: I would agree with your assessment that R are usually tandem or inline twins (I don’t think they make inlines any more) that looks like a 3040 panel and if it is the bottom horizontal can not have a tandem, but the 5 horizontal slots above that one can or 10 breakers. So look at the part number for the panel and if there is a 3040 in it’s number you can use some for tandems just not the bottom.

Comment: No need to apologize for the formatting.  [Related question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/100175/mystery-circuit-breaker-discovered-in-qo-panel), BTW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are the **only** spaces that **tandem breakers (Type QO-T)** can be installed on. They may physically fit other spaces, but they are not allowed because the label says they are not allowed elsewhere.

They can be used for non-tandem breakers and dual breakers as well.

Read the text regarding acceptable breaker types for each. Other than those spaces allowing QO-T the acceptable types are identical. So if your breakers are the appropriate QO types, they are fine to be located there.

It's a bit puzzling that the one label (door) shows 29R and 30R, but the other disallows that - best to follow the more restrictive (29&30 are **not** to be tandems, as per the inside label)